# Use Stocks data type in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Public Function stockquote(ByRef ticker as String) As Double
    Const exchange as String = "XNAS:"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1")
            .ClearContents
            .Value = exchange & ticker
            .ConvertToLinkedDataType serviceid:= 268435456, LanguageCulture:= "en-US"
        End With
        
        stockquote = .Evaluate("=" & "A1" & ".Price")
    End With
End Function
```

Is there a way to convert to stocks data type without accessing the worksheet? I don't want to use STOCKHISTORY function as it has its own limitations.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `without accessing the worksheet`.

Comment: @taller Don't want to assign string at cell "A1" of Sheet1 and then convert to stocks data type.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping that there was a more elegant way to do this where Excel gives access to the linked data type. I believe that:

```
stockquote = application.FieldValue(Range("A1"), "Price")
```

should work.